# Error using grunt with sass?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, sass, gruntjs

I'm using Windows 7 and trying to use Grunt for workflow. I've never used it before and am trying to make sure everything is installed and running correctly. I've installed everything (Node.js, Ruby, Sass, Git, yo, Bower, Grunt) and everything up as far as Grunt is working fine. I'm testing out Grunt on a previous project from my company that works on all the other machines in the office (both PC and Mac) and I can start it watching my files, but when I edit a `.scss` file that is being watched and save it I get

`Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\x9D" to UTF-8 in conversion from Windows-1252 to UTF-8. Use --trace for backtrace. Warning: Exited with error code 1`

I've tried forcing all `.scss` files to encode UTF-8, changed defaults on Sublime Text to always use UTF-8, checked filenames for unusual characters, and it hasn't fixed anything. Any suggestions for what else I can try? Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Sounds like there is a funky character in one of the files (not the file name). I'd probably use a divide and conquer strategy to find the offending file.